# AWS MSK (Kafka) metrics issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, metrics

At my firm we have a production MSK cluster running Kafka v2.5.1 (created last September), where the available CloudWatch metrics categories are:

- by Broker ID, Cluster Name, Topic
- by Broker ID, Cluster Name
- by Cluster Name

Now, I created a Dev MSK cluster running, again, 2.5.1, and I see this ADDITIONAL metrics category:

- **by Cluster Name, Consumer Group, Topic**

This new category contains the all-important OFFSET **LAG** metric.

Why is there such a disparity between the two clusters? Both have the "Basic" monitoring option enabled. Is there a way to "upgrade" the older cluster so that it will include that crucial metric?

Thanks for any clues

Comment: The [Amazon MSK consumer lag metrics announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/amazon-msk-offers-consumer-lag-metrics-select-topic-level-metrics-free/) reads "*For existing clusters, these metrics will be enabled next time the cluster is upgraded with the latest operating system patch.*"

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Do you know how this can be arranged? I can't find any relevant info in the docs. Would rebooting the brokers one by one do the trick, perhaps?